# Capturing all names in line with regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture all words starting with upper case going one after another and preceding the `Inc` word. For example, to capture `Test Alphabet` from the whole row `Parent company Test Alphabet Inc. announced`. I made a regular expression pattern:

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)+
```

which takes all words starting with upper case. But it grabs `Parent`, which is not needed. When I try to limit the condition in this way:

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)+ (?=(Inc))
```

it takes only `Alphabet` and doesn't grab `Test` word which is needed.
Please help me understand how to grab all words starting with upper case following one another and preceding `Inc` word?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*(?=\s+Inc\.)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.X : Regex to find all company names ending in ".inc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316157/python-2-x-regex-to-find-all-company-names-ending-in-inc)

Comment: Also, which language or regex engine are you using? P.S. Using `{1}` is pointless since that's the default.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thnaks a lot, it works perfect!

Comment: @ctwheels Are you sure it is a dupe?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's a dupe apart from not capturing `Inc.`, so I guess not, but close

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead regex to match:

```
[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?=\s*(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s+)*Inc\.)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OVn3KO/1)

- `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*` matches a word that starts with uppercase letter
- Lookahead expression inside `(?=...)` ensures that we have 0 or more uppercase words followed by `Inc.` ahead of current word.

Comment: @anubgava thanks! As far as I can see it sees `Alphabet` and `Test` as to separate words?

Comment: To match it as a single string with spaces in between use: `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*(?=\s+Inc\.)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
((?:[A-Z]\w*\s*)*\s?)(?=\sInc)
```

It capture the company name as one group. It takes one shortcut using `\w` as allowed characters in the name. This means names can be a mixture of upper and lower case letters, as well as `_`. If this is unwanted behavior, change the `\w` to `[a-z]` for lower case letters only, or `[A-Za-z]` for mixed lower and upper case.

[See it here at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/6WuJuN/2)

Comment: You can save a lot of steps and cut the space at the end by using `(?:[A-Z]\w*\s*?)+(?=\s+Inc)` instead.

Comment: @ctwheels True, if just matching is OK. That doesn't capture the name as requested. But I agree with you.